# SQL Server 2008 - Save each "while loop" result to a different file

Tags: sql-server, while-loop

I'm using a double while loop to get a lot of results from several different tables. I get everything I need (500+ subjects, each with 1000+ rows), but each comes into a different grid. I would like to save each "while" result to a different .csv file. Is there any way

Comment: why cant you insert output of each while loop into temp table and export temp table to CSV

Comment: SQL Server doesn't have "grids". Exporting is supported using SSIS and/or bcp since the 1990s. What have you tried, where is the code (script? package?). What is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might be possible to do using `SQLCMD` or `BCP`, but will be quite cumbersome to code, using quite a few variables and dynamic SQL.

If faced with this scenario, I would personally go with an SSIS package -

1. Use package variables to generate destination filenames dynamically
2. Use a for each loop container instead of the while loop
3. Put a dataflow task inside the container and use the `Select` code as source and the file from step one as the destination

It is pretty easy to do.